# case (let name, let x)

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Hello I am working on some basic swift exercise's. This one is over switch statements. I have looked high and low for but cant quite get the right explanation for this code.

```
let tuple = ("Matt", 30)
switch (tuple) {
case (let name, let x) where x >= 0 && x <= 2:
  print("\(name) is a infant")
case (let name, let x) where x >= 3 && x <= 12:
  print("\(name) is a child")
case (let name, let x) where x >= 13 && x <= 19:
  print("\(name) is a teenager")
case (let name, let x) where x >= 20 && x <= 39:
  print("\(name) is an adult")
case (let name, let x) where x >= 40 && x <= 60:
  print("\(name) is a middle aged")
case (let name, let x) where x >= 61:
  print("\(name) is a elderly")
default:
  print("Invalid age")
```

}

Not the whole block just:

```
 case (let name, let x)
```

What exactly is happening here? How does name refer to "Matt"? Why dont you have to type some more code creating a string known as "Matt"? Like this:

```
let name = "Matt"
```

Also what is going on with the let x part? Does using the constant,:

```
let tuple = ("Matt", 30)
```

let the computer know that there already is a String and Int in the Switch statement? So that whenever any String is used it will refer to "Matt"? Like if were to do something like this:

```
case(let dog, let z)
```

Why doesn't that do the same thing as "let name, let x"?

Also how is "x" related to 30? As far as I can see "x" would be a string but it is being taken as an Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple is just a variable that carries more than one value. In your example the tuple is of the type `(String, Int)` because that's how you first defined it.

Like when you do `let name = "Matt"` this is just doing that except with an `Int` alongside the string.

The switch is then then checking that tuple based on the pattern matching.

The `(let name, let x)` is just taking the values from that tuple and inserting them into the variables named `name` and `x` so that they can be used. Without this you would not be able to print the name or age in the code.

If you didn't care about the name you could do...

```
case (_, let x):
print("This person is \(x) years old")
```

You can't print the name here because you haven't put it into a variable name.

You could also do `case (let dog, let z):`. This would work and now the variable `dog` would be a `String` with the value "Matt". Except it doesn't really make sense to do this because the value is a name be not a dog. :-)

If you had made your first line as...

```
let tuple = ("Oliver", 33)
```

Then the name variable would be "Oliver" and the X would be 33.

Comment: Thanks for the response your answer cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the `switch` statement you set the `tuple` containing a string `Matt` and integer `30`. The `case` sets the variables `name` and `age` to these values and compares `age` only.

You could use any variable names, so your `dog` would be the name and `z` would be the age. The compiler doesn't care about the names, as long as there are an appropriate amount of them for the tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the response!